# tracking.js works with sample image but not more complex data

Tags: tracking.js

I'm trying to use [tracking.js](https://trackingjs.com/) for color detection. I'm testing the code locally, and can replicate the example results when using [the sample image](https://trackingjs.com/bower/tracking.js/examples/assets/psmove.png) provided in the tracking.js [live demo](https://trackingjs.com/examples/color_hello_world.html).

I can also add a new color and get the tracker to identify the fourth bulb in that sample:

```
tracking.ColorTracker.registerColor('#8CF0BE', function(r, g, b) {
  if (r < 150 && g > 225 && b < 200) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
});
```

**But when I swap out the default image on my local test page with the one below** (which is from [an unrelated but excellent SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/), **nothing at all gets highlighted/boxed.**

[image: Railway switch in trainyard]
<sub>[Image](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Entroncamento_do_Transpraia.JPG) by Mecanismo, via Wikimedia Commons. Used under the [CC BY-SA 3.0](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license.</sub>

I'm specifically trying to get the switch to light up, with this color definition:

```
tracking.ColorTracker.registerColor('orangered', function(r, g, b) {
  if (r > g && r > b) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
});
```

I used a digital color meter to determine that all the switches in the pixel have red values in the 150-200 range, green values in the 30-100 range, and blue values in the 10-100 range (and mostly not the high ends of those scales).

For what it's worth, I know the custom color definition itself isn't *completely* broken, because it does have an effect on that initial sample image:

[image: Sample image with highlighting]

What am I doing wrong or not understanding here?